# How to do a joins with the result of an array using squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

I have [squeel](http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/)  installed and would like to do the following:

```
@branches = Branch.near(@latlon) #This provides an array of nearby branches

@dispensers = Dispenser.joins{@branches} #This does not work
```

I could geocode my dispensers, but I'd generally prefer the option above, if possible using active record, or active record + squeel. There must be some easy way to pull this off in Rails.

Comment: Dispenser.where{branch_id >> @branches} ??? You can't join an array, but you can add it to the where clause.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your models? Like what kind of association they have with each other.